# I want to split one file into two different file using perl script

Tags: perl

I want to split a file into two files.
If file name is `example.txt` then it will be divided in two file like `EX1.txt` or `EX2.txt`.

The splitting depends on the second field in each line. Example: if the HDR line has `TEA003890459` as second field, then the output will go to `EX1.txt`
But if the HDR has `TEA003886004` then the output goes into `EX2.txt`.
I also want to count the claim numbers.

I want to do this using following logic:

```
if Header-Row then
    if Dummy cost center then
        write to Gas file
        keep in mind: Claim-Nummer (eg. Array or Hash)
    else
        write to normal file
    end if
else if Detail-Row then
    if kept Claim-Nummer then
        write to Gas file
    else
       write to normal file
    end if
end if
```

The file contains the following data:

```
HDR^TEA003890459^082582^Mohd Jamil^Jamili Fahmi Bin^^458^+^92000^+^92000^+^0000^+^0000^+^0000^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^20130307^^^^^^^222^MY0BD^2^jamilifahmi.mohdjamil@se1.bp.com^      MY0BCC#6482362304                                 
DTL^TEA003890459^E^MY0BCC#6482362304              641301137^+^47000^MFA^20130209^Medical Expenses [Family]^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Medical
DTL^TEA003890459^E^MY0BCC#6482362304              641301137^+^45000^MGE^20130304^Medical Expenses  (Employee clinica^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Medical
HDR^TEA003886004^082770^Bin Omar^Mohamad Fadzlizam^^458^+^135800^+^135800^+^0000^+^0000^+^0000^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^20130307^^^^^^^222^MY0BD^4^mohamad.omar@se1.bp.com^      MY0BCC#6485163100                                 
DTL^TEA003886004^E^MY0BCC#6485163100              641301137^+^25000^MFA^20130221^Medical Expenses [Family]^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Claim
DTL^TEA003886004^E^MY0BCC#6485163100              641301137^+^37150^MFA^20130224^Medical Expenses [Family]^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Claim
DTL^TEA003886004^E^MY0BCC#6485163100              641301137^+^23650^MFA^20130226^Medical Expenses [Family]^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Claim
DTL^TEA003886004^E^MY0BCC#6485163100              641301137^+^50000^MGE^20130304^Medical Expenses  (Employee clinica^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Claim
HDR^TEA003886162^082792^Lim^Jia Jieh^^458^+^280400^+^280400^+^0000^+^0000^+^0000^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^20130305^^^^^^^222^MY0BD^4^jia_jieh.lim@se1.bp.com^      MY0BCC#6482363474                                 
DTL^TEA003886162^E^MY0BCC#6482363474              641301137^+^110000^MGE^20130131^Medical Expenses  (Employee clinica^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Medical claim 31/1,20/2,28/2
DTL^TEA003886162^E^MY0BCC#6482363474              641301137^+^60000^MGE^20130220^Medical Expenses  (Employee clinica^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Medical claim 31/1,20/2,28/2
DTL^TEA003886162^E^MY0BCC#6482363474              641301137^+^50400^MGE^20130220^Medical Expenses  (Employee clinica^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Medical claim 31/1,20/2,28/2
DTL^TEA003886162^E^MY0BCC#6482363474              641301137^+^60000^MGE^20130228^Medical Expenses  (Employee clinica^^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^0^^C16Medical claim 31/1,20/2,28/2
```

Comment: I tried to rephrase your question. Please check that I didn't accidentally change the meaning. **Questions:** ① What is `TDR`? ② What is “Dummy cost center”? ③ What is a “*Gas* file”? ③ Wouldn't your example file be split into three files? ④ Your file looks like Comma-seperated data (CSV) with `^` as field seperator. Can you acknowledge this?

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation and psuedo code and example data seem to tell a different story

However to read the second field, once the file is opened and to sort as described

```
open(my $ex1,">EX1.txt")||die"EX1.txt $!";
open(my $ex2,">EX2.txt")||die"EX2.txt $!";
$wanted="TEA003890459";
while($line = <$ifile>) {

   @field=split('\^',$line);
   if ($field[1] eq $wanted) {    # fields start from 0 so 1 is the second field
     print $ex1 $line;
   else {
     print $ex2 $line;
   }
}
```

EDIT: fix split arg

Comment: The first argument in `split` is a regex, where `^` is a metacharacter. → `split /\^/` or something.

Comment: Instead of adding `EDIT: fix split arg` why don't you put that in the edit summary?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

foreach (<>) {
        my @out = split(/\^/,$_);
        if ($out[0] eq 'HDR') {
                close OUTFILE;
                open OUTFILE,">>$out[1].txt" or die();
        } elsif ($out[0] eq 'DTL') {
                print OUTFILE $_;
        }
}
```

Run with:

```
./split.pl < infile.txt
```

Will split out to files for each header type. You can use a Linux wc command to count entries for each.

Comment: Why did you use 2 arg [`open`](http://p3rl.org/open "perldoc -f open"), instead of 3 arg [`open`](http://p3rl.org/open "perldoc -f open")? Why didn't you include [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24! "perldoc -v '$!'") in the `or`[`die`](http://p3rl.org/die "perldoc -f die")?